# in JointJs, how to prevent element with ports from being moved, but still allow its ports to work?

Tags: javascript, diagram, jointjs

I have a JointJs element with ports. I'd like the element not to be movable within the diagram, but still allow the user to connect its ports to other elements. If I use the `interactive` attribute in the Paper to disallow interactions for these elements, then it becomes unmovable, but it's ports no longer work.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interactive` can be both boolean or an object. Object defines more specific cases. It can have properties such as:

`labelMove`
`arrowheadMove`
`vertexMove`
`useLinkTools` applicable for links and `elementMove` applicable for elements.

so in your case `paper.setInteractivity({elementMove: false})` should do the trick